# Scala: Extracting columns from a DataFrame and adding it to a empty data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a empty data frame and populate the data from another data frame based on certain conditions.

For example:
DataFrame1 is empty 
DataFrame2 = Has the following data

```
ID |  Date    |  Type
---------------------
1     02012001    Car
2     02011994    SUV
```

I want to add only "id" and "date" column from DataFrame2 to DataFrame1 (which is empty).

Answer (score 4):

rdd is immutable, it cannot be updated. you can do it like

```
val dataframe2 =  dataframe1.select("ID","DATE")
```